# Blazor Webassembly App display image from server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

What is simplest way to display images at client side component, downloaded/kept at server in Blazor Webassembly project? [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okPmx.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your image in **wwwroot** folder, and it will be serve as any other static files.
And don't forget to add the static files  middleware in your server's middlewares pipeline.

**Startup.cd**

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
...
    app.UseStaticFiles();
...
}
```

Comment: wwwroot is at BlazorApp1.Client, which displays images correctly, but what if I want to do this at BlazorApp1.Server, where I've uploaded images? I've created wwwroot at Blazor1App.Server and now WebRootPath isn't null as earlier was, but I don't have access to this resources by browser, also with all other localhost IP addresses set in appsettings.json in BlazorApp1.Client and BlazorApp1.Server

Comment: Add `app.UseStaticFiles` in you server middlewares pipeline. (in Startup.Configure)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved everything.

Comment: @Barnabas I tried, with no success. Would you be so kind to share a code snippet with your solution?