# Blazor WASM: How to let Client display Images from wwwroot file

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor web app project with a webassembly rendermode. I am wondering how to let the client solution access images that are stored in the wwwroot folder in the server solution.

The purpose of this is because i have a page in the client solution, which i would like to display an image.

Solutions that I have tried/read up, but failed to understand/implement, are:

[Blazor Webassembly App display image from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011924/blazor-webassembly-app-display-image-from-server?rq=4)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I tried using a HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(/Images/picture.png) but i receive an error "An invalid request URI was provided. However i feel that this approach is not the step in the right direction.

Comment: When you say access do you mean display via an `<img ...`  ?

Comment: @BrianParker yes. I do mean via an <img />

Comment: `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync` should work if you want to do something on the image in your code, but maybe you forget to set its `BaseAddress`? (if you just want to display the image on your page, the current answer should be the best approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative path as shown below. Note how I can have the same folder in both projects `wwwroot` folder and address them the same.

```html
<img src="images/icon-512x512.png" height="64" />
<img src="images/StackIcon-512.png" height="64" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping. Just to clarify, the solution is to create a wwwroot folder into the client solution? Because normally when I first created the project, the client solution did not have any wwwroot folder. Also could you explain to me if there are any downsides. And the difference between the two wwwroot folders in the two solutions. Thank you so much for your time and sorry to trouble you.

Comment: @AmirNakhoda it's just like that you are writing `<img src="images/icon-512x512.png">` in a pure `html` file. the explorer will send a web request to get the the image and display it here.